# How to parse a numbered sequence from a List of filenames?

Tags: c#, parsing, c#-3.0, filenames

I would like to automatically *parse* a **range** of **numbered sequences** from an *already sorted* `List<FileData>` of filenames by checking which part of the filename changes.

Here is an example (file extension has already been removed):

> **First filename**: `IMG_0000`
>   **Last filename**: `IMG_1000`
>   **Numbered Range I need**: `0000` and `1000`

Except I need to deal with *every* possible type of file naming convention such as:

> 0000 ... 9999
>   20080312_0000 ... 20080312_9999
>   IMG_0000 - Copy ... IMG_9999 - Copy
>   8er_green3_00001 .. 8er_green3_09999
>   etc.

- I would like the entire 0-padded range e.g. `0001` not just `1`
- The sequence number is 0-padded e.g. `0001`
- The sequence number can be located anywhere e.g. `IMG_0000 - Copy`
- The range can start and end with anything i.e. doesn't have to start with `1` and end with `9999`
- Numbers may appear multiple times in the filename of the sequence e.g. `20080312_0000`

Whenever I get something working for 8 random test cases, the 9th test breaks everything and I end up re-starting from scratch.

I've currently been comparing *only* the first and last filenames (as opposed to iterating through all filenames):

```
void FindRange(List<FileData> files, out string startRange, out string endRange)
{
    string firstFile = files.First().ShortName;
    string lastFile = files.Last().ShortName;

    ...
}
```

Does anyone have any clever ideas? Perhaps something with Regex?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. What is the input and what is the expected output? Could you post some of your test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're guaranteed to know the files end with the number (eg. _\d+), and are sorted, just grab the first and last elements and that's your range. If the filenames are all the same, you can sort the list to get them in order numerically. Unless I'm missing something obvious here -- where's the problem?

Comment: Not always at the end, see example: `IMG_0000 - Copy ... IMG_9999 - Copy`

Comment: Yes they are sorted, and I already have the first and last elements. As Kirk mentioned the number can be randomly located. I just want the range start/end numbers (e.g. "0001" and "9999") as substrings because currently I'm using 6 functions to locate the text _surrounding_ the number and it's all gotten out of hand.

Comment: They should still sort if they numbers are located in the same position and zero-filled. Just use a regex to pull them out: \d+

Comment: That's half the problem - determining their position.

Comment: Why do you care about their position? Just match on \d+ and you'll grab all the numbers. If you know the length, use it, i.e. \d{5} for five digits.

Comment: Many possible solutions, this ended up being the leanest and cleanest. I just had to iterate the `MatchCollection` of both sets to find which one differs, since one possible scenario is to have multiple numbers in the filename.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you found a solution that you liked and that's clean.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I will assume that the numbers are always zero-padded so that they are the same length.  If not then bigger headaches lie ahead.

Secondly, assume that the file names are *exactly* the same apart from the increment number component.

If these assumptions are true then the algorithm should be to look at each character in the first and last filenames to determine which same-positioned characters do not match.

```
var start = String.Empty;
var end = String.Empty;

for (var index = 0; index < firstFile.Length; index++)
{
    char c = firstFile[index];

    if (filenames.Any(filename => filename[index] != c))
    {            
        start += firstFile[index];
        end += lastFile[index];
    }
}    
// convert to int if required
```

edit:  Changed to check every filename until a difference is found.  Not as efficient as it could be but very simple and straightforward.

Comment: Yes I am assuming that they are at least zero-padded. Nice try but it doesn't work if the first name is "0000" and last is "0070" because the last "0" will match.

Comment: Ah of course.  So how many file names do you have, and how fast do you need to process them?  The simplest solution is to check every single file name... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Somewhere between 2 and 500k, depends on the project. Time isn't _really_ important, though it shouldn't take very long to scan through 500k strings anyways?

Comment: The Any() operator stops as soon as it is satisfied.  If you want to speed this up, add some more conditions - e.g. if you are sure that you only need to look at numbers, then add `if (!Char.IsNumber(c)) continue;` to move to the next character.

Comment: String operations are really quite quick; if it's not required in a real time system then it will be fine but if it is integrated into something else you need to test it.  500k strings isn't that many.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to parse out the numbers from the filenames:

```
^.+\w(\d+)[^\d]*$
```

From these parsed strings, find the maximum length, and left-pad any that are less than the maximum length with zeros.

Sort these padded strings alphabetically. Take the first and last from this sorted list to give you your min and max numbers.

Comment: This will only work if the number appears at the end of the filename.  You could put a * in there then will get confusing if there are multiple numbers preceded by an underscore in the filename.

Comment: I think OP needs to look at the _changing_ component of the filename to determine the correct part, rather than just look for numeric parts.

Comment: @Kirk - I edited the regex to match the final group of numbers, whether they appear at the end of the string or not. In plain english, it says "match anything, followed by a word character, followed by a group of numbers that may or may not be followed by anything that is not numbers". Regarding your second comment, if this is the case, I have no idea how to do this! Seems like the solution would be non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  It works with all of the examples that you have provided and it **assumes the input array to be sorted.**

Note that it doesn't look exclusively for numbers; it looks for a consistent sequence of characters that might differ across all of the strings.  So if you provide it with `{"0000", "0001", "0002"}` it will hand back "0" and "2" as the start and end strings, since that's the only part of the strings that differ.  If you give it `{"0000", "0010",  "0100"}`, it will give you back "00" and "10".

But if you give it `{"0000", "0101"}`, it will whine since the differing parts of the string are not contiguous.  If you would like this behavior modified so it will return everything from the first differing character to the last, that's fine; I can make that change.  But if you are feeding it a ton of filenames that will have sequential changes to the number region, this should not be a problem.

```
public static class RangeFinder
{
    public static void FindRange(IEnumerable<string> strings,
        out string startRange, out string endRange)
    {
        using (var e = strings.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (!e.MoveNext())
                throw new ArgumentException("strings", "No elements.");

            if (e.Current == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("strings",
                    "Null element encountered at index 0.");

            var template = e.Current;

            // If an element in here is true, it means that index differs.
            var matchMatrix = new bool[template.Length];

            int index = 1;

            string last = null;
            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                if (e.Current == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("strings",
                        "Null element encountered at index " + index + ".");

                last = e.Current;
                if (last.Length != template.Length)
                    throw new ArgumentException("strings",
                        "Element at index " + index + " has incorrect length.");

                for (int i = 0; i < template.Length; i++)
                    if (last[i] != template[i])
                        matchMatrix[i] = true;
            }

            // Verify the matrix:
            // * There must be at least one true value.
            // * All true values must be consecutive.
            int start = -1;
            int end = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < matchMatrix.Length; i++) {
                if (matchMatrix[i]) {
                    if (end != -1)
                        throw new ArgumentException("strings",
                            "Inconsistent match matrix; no usable pattern discovered.");

                    if (start == -1)
                        start = i;
                } else {
                    if (start != -1 && end == -1)
                        end = i;
                }
            }

            if (start == -1)
                throw new ArgumentException("strings",
                    "Strings did not vary; no usable pattern discovered.");

            if (end == -1)
                end = matchMatrix.Length;

            startRange = template.Substring(start, end - start);
            endRange = last.Substring(start, end - start);
        }
    }
}
```